# Angular - Circular dependency between models

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dependecies problem with models relation in my Angular project. It´s maybe an architecture problem, I don´t know. I have an User model that has Books, and a Book model that has Users.

With this code I got the error:

Circular dependency detected

#### user.model.ts

```js
import { BookModel } from './book.model';


export class UserModel {

    id: number = 0;
    email: string = "";

    books: BookModel [] = [];

    constructor(){};

    parse(jsonData: any){
        if (jsonData['id']) {
            this.id = jsonData['id'];
        }

        if (jsonData['email']) {
            this.email = jsonData['email'];
        }

        if (jsonData['books']) {
            for (let i = 0; i < jsonData['books'].length; i++) {
                let book = new BookModel();
                book.parse(jsonData['books'][i]);
                this.books.push(book);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### book.model.ts

```js
import { UserModel } from './user.model';

export class BookModel {

    id: number = 0;
    name: string = "";

    users: UserModel [] = [];

    constructor(){};

    parse(jsonData: any){
        if (jsonData['id']) {
            this.id = jsonData['id'];
        }
        
        if (jsonData['name']) {
            this.name = jsonData['name'];
        }

        if (jsonData['users']) {
            for (let i = 0; i < jsonData['users'].length; i++) {
                let user = new UserModel();
                user.parse(jsonData['users'][i]);
                this.users.push(user);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found two solutions but both are not good in my opinion:

The first solution I found is change, for example, `books: BookModel []` to `bookIds: number []`. I think this solution will make me work a lot more than the original code to get the related information.

The second one I found is use an auxiliar Model. For example 'AuxBookModel' and 'AuxUserModel'. AuxUserModel has the same attributes than UserModel and AuxBookModel the same with BookModel. This way in UserModel the code shows like: `books: AuxBookModel [] = []`. But with this solution I need to create a lot of new models because my application is big and duplicate the code is not a good idea.

What is the right way to organizate models?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an interface named `IUserModel` and use that with `BookModel`, and then have the `UserModel` implement that interface. Your problem is neither an architectural or Angular issue.

You have a circular dependency path and TypeScript can not compile the source code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I´ve tryed that solution, but this way I lose the books information that are inside the users that are inside the books.  My application shows dependecy warning, but it actually runs, so can I simply disabled the warnings?

Comment: @JerogBesteneza you should create interfaces for both models, and no you should not disable this warning.